# React-router Redirect error when using object instead of string for "to"

Tags: javascript, redirect, react-router

I am using react-router and want to add a redirect. This is the Redirect I am using

```
<Redirect from="/" to={{ pathname: "/sth", search: "?tst=1" }} />
```

For some unknown reason I get the following error from react:

```
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `to` of type `object` supplied to `Redirect`, expected `string`.
    in Redirect
```

I was not able to find why this doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Which version of `react-router` are you using?

Comment: I'm guessing you're trying to use RRv4 but you have a different version installed. Double check that v4 is installed, it definitely supports to as an object. https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/modules/Redirect.js#L11

Comment: Thanks, @TylerMcGinnis you are right. I am using v3.0.2. I quickly glanced in the source code from the CDN and saw that in the propTypes both object and string are allowed, but actually this line was not enabled (it is in if(false){...} statement)

Comment: @djvuk Cool. Just added my response as an answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you're trying to use RRv4 but you have a different version installed. Double check that v4 is installed, it definitely supports `to` as an object - [seen here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/modules/Redirect.js#L11)